# github and XCode 4.2 issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, github, xcode4.2

I am having a lot of issues with integrating XCode 4.2 git and github. For some reason doing control+command+c always gives me an error of:

```
The operation could not be performed because no valid working copies were found.
```

I check on Windows->Organizer->Repositories and the repo is there. When I click on the folder that has the name on my project and commit using the repository control, I can do commits, now the issue is that the Push is always grayed out. How do I get around this issue? Tried restarting several times and it didn't help at all

Comment: Regarding the push operation, would http://stackoverflow.com/a/8248877/6309 help?

Answer (score 0):

xcode4's version control sucks.
you can try `gitx(l)` instead ([download it here](http://gitx.laullon.com/))
Anyway, any GUI git client can't do much on git functions. trying to learn git command on console is a better choice.

Comment: yea, I was using the git command from the terminal all the time.. just wanted to migrate to xcode

Answer (score -1):

There is a series of git basics video tutorials - you can even download the video files themsleves in hi def at http://www.ava.co.uk/git - 9 vids in all about 40 mins - they get quite a few thumbs up. We also invested in Smart git - and its almost very good.

Comment: not asking how git works.. I fully understand how git and github works. I am having issues integrating it with xcode

Comment: I'm sorry that was not clear from your question. I took my lead from the "trying to learn git command on console is a better choice." which at the time you had not commented on...