# Loading Xcode 4 git repository onto Bitbucket

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode4, bitbucket

I have an Xcode project with a few commits, and now I would like to load it onto Bitbucket, without losing my commit history. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new repository, and push to it from Xcode like normal. It will preserve all of the commit history.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the [Import Code into (BitBucket) repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project), and select a Git repo on your local workstation.
The fact that this local repo is managed by XCode4 doesn't matter.

After the import, you can add your Bitbucket repo as a remote, with an [https address](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+SSH+Protocol+with+bitbucket), as mentioned in "[Bitbucket + XCode 4.2 + Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131692/bitbucket-xcode-4-2-git)" (even though the XCode GUI might not be enough, and some command lines might be needed).

Comment: Thank you, [Michael Davidovich](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2209092/michael-davidovich), for fixing the broken link.