# How do I configure Git in Xcode to work with BitBucket

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, bitbucket

I have a project which I have been on for ages which is not connected to any source code repository.

I want to start using BitBucket now, however I am not sure how to go about it.  I have created a project in BitBucket.

Should I now clone and check out in Xcode or should I add a repository in xcode.  Anyone have any idea?

I have tried cloning using the URL from bitbucket but it just comes back with an error in Xcode

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of 2017, xCode now automatically creates repositories for new projects. To push to a new BitBucket repo, go to 'Source Control' > 'Commit...' in xCode and make your first local commit.

Next open a terminal and navigate to to the top-level directory of your project. If you `ls -a` in here you should see the `.git/` directory has been created. In the same directory, add your remote repo with the following (replace with your username/team name and repo name):

```
git remote add origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
```

Go back into xCode, go to 'Source Control' > 'Push...'. You'll be prompted to enter your BitBucket password. Press OK and you're done! Source control commands will now be working within xCode.

Answer (score 26):

I've met the same problem and here's how I solved it:

1. (Assume your project is not already under local source control) Create a new project under LOCAL source control (Please note that adding remote source control at this stage may not be successful)
2. Make this new project a clone of your old project - drag files, add frameworks, etc.
3. In menu "Source Control" ->  -> "Configure "
   In the new window, click on "Remotes" -> "+" -> "Add Remote"
4. - Name: anything (you can use "BitBucket")
   - Address: https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
5. "Source Control" -> "Commit"
6. Select "push to remote" at the left bottom corner
7. Click "Commit"
8. Check on BitBucket website to see if it's actually pushed to it

Comment: You and your answer are my new best friends.

Comment: I had to create the the git repo on bitbucket before xcode would push to it. ie: xcode couldn't create the remote repo for me.

Comment: Also, it seems xcode does an initial commit when it sets up the local repo, so you should be ok to just "push to remote" without doing a "commit" first.

Answer (score 15):

I did that through command line and it is fairly straightforward.

1. create a new repo on bitbucket
2. assuming your xcode project is not under local git version control yet
3. go to command line, cd to your xcode project directory, and the follow the bitbucket doc: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project

   ```
   git init
   git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<user_id>/<repo>.git
   git add .
   git commit -am 'init commit'
   git push -u origin master
   ```
4. go back to xcode and you should be able to interact with bitbucket through xcode from this point on

Answer (score 14):

Using the following URL structure

```
https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

(Taken from [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket)) did the job for me

Comment: Or even with password and Xcode will ask to save it: `https://accountname:password@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git`

Comment: I tried this in the new project wizard, and it didn't work.  It worked easily after creating the local Git repo with the wizard and then setting up source control later with the existing project.

Comment: It says "Server Unreachable" when I do this.

Comment: If you meet "Server Unreachable" when doing this, please check my answer below for another method to solve this.

Comment: ssh link, e.g. git@bitbucket.org/xxx doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to:

- create your local Git repo through XCode and add your code there
- in command line, add the remote 'origin' toward your BitBucket repo, along with your ssh credentials (in `~/.ssh/config`): see

  - "[Bitbucket + XCode 4.2 + Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131692/bitbucket-xcode-4-2-git)".
  - "[Using the SSH protocol with bitbucket](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+SSH+protocol+with+bitbucket)"
- do at least one "`git push myrepo origin master`" to initiate the first push

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me, I will also copy and paste the instructions in case the link goes away.

http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2016/02/send-xcode-project-to-bitbucket.html

Sending a non-git Xcode Project to BitBucket from GitHub is the most popular place to host your repos but if you are looking for a free service for teams that are 5 members or less then take a look at BitBucket. Here are instructions for moving a local Xcode project onto BitBucket. (Note: if you opted for a local Git when you created your project you should be able to skip steps 3 and 4.)

-Sign-up for BitBucket and create a repo

-In Xcode go to Source Control menu

-Select "Create a working copy ...."

-Select project and press Create in dialog window

-Return to Source Control menu and select  -> Configure  ...

-Click "Remotes" tab

-Press add "+"

-Copy and paste the https address you see at the top right of your repo page into the remote location in Xcode

-Go to Source Control menu and select Push... to upload the project

**Pushing code updates to BitBucket
Now you have it set up whenever you want to push code to the project:**

-Go to Source Control menu and select Commit

-Write a commit note and uncheck anything not to be included in the commit

-Return to Source Control menu and select push

-Select the correct branch and Push

**Pulling code down from BitBucket repo
To get code provided by others down from BitBucket:**

-Go to Source Control menu and select Pull.

Answer (score 0):

I use SourceTree and Xcode 6.1 and in my case I first create a repository on bitbucket, then I clone my repository on an empty folder (using SourceTree or via command line) then when you create the new project on XCode in that folder, you can commit push and pull normally from XCode

Answer (score 0):

I found [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esfxbWBimtw) and it helped me a lot, used [this Atlasssian help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) for ssh authentication, and encountered an Xcode problem for which the solution can be found [in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428356/xcode-git-failed-to-commit-files/34166769#34166769).

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way is go to

> Xcode > preference > @accounts > click '+' button on corner left

... then this popup will appear ...

[image]

just click Bitbucket Cloud ...

[image]

Enter ID with password...
And that's it...