# XCode (git) failed to commit files

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I just got started using GIT with Xcode and when I tried to commit an older project I've been working on I ran in to the following error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jafzgxhit0h4d1e/Screenshot%202014-06-26%2005.37.04.png

If I uncheck the Parse.framework/Headers directory I get this error instead

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqrpelqarp0liq4/Screenshot%202014-06-26%2005.38.28.png

My current .gitignore looks like this:

```
# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-ignore-the-pods-directory-in-source-control
#
# Pods/
```

I'd be supergreatful for a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion, use Free App SourceTree http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ way better than xcode.

Comment: SourceTree was really sweet, thanks!

Comment: Another suggestion, http://www.gitboxapp.com could make it easy for a git toddler!

Comment: Another suggestion : use the command line.  This is a little higher learning curve, but you will understand git. I'm not say only use terminal, I use SourceTree all the time.  I just use command line more.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem was to navigate to the directory in terminal and then type:

- git init
- git add .
- git commit "COMMENT"

Then I restarted xcode, went back to xcode and pushed the project from there.

Comment: And also make sure there is not `.git` folder inside your project, there should be only one `.git` folder and it should be in the root folder where you have fired `git init`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found the solution [there](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application-in-xcode-7/).
The problem is that Xcode doesn't want to commit if your user settings are not correctly set.
The solution is putting this in the terminal:

> ```
> xcrun git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.com
> xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
> ```